# Edit InfoPath columns in Quick edit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, online

Is there is a way to Edit InfoPath columns in Quick edit view, without using InfoPath Forms with SharePoint 2013/Online 365

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you go to the list in SharePoint.

'List' tab, 'list settings'.

Then you can edit existing columns to some extent - there are less options than in InfoPath.

You can also create additional columns if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Creating form using infopath will create an app in site contents page open the settings for that app and it looks like the image attached. In the column  section all the columns are displayed open the column you want to edit, edit thr fields and select Ok

[image]

This may help you

Answer (score 0):

when you are publishing your InfoPath form to a SharePoint Form library you can choose columns to promote to SharePoint list columns. Normally such a promoted column will be readonly in SharePoint, but you can enable it to be editable by checking the checkbox 'Allow users to edit data in this field by using a datasheet or properties page' (Modity the promoted column in InfoPath Designer).